# Busybox - How to delete looping creations of busybox containers

Tags: kubernetes, busybox

I created a namespace inside Kubernetes and tried to create a container using the following command:

`kubectl run busybox -it ----image=busybox -- sh`

But now, everytime I delete the pod using `kubectl delete pods --all`, it deletes the pod that was just created and it automatically recreates a new pod. I looked through the documentation but am unable to figure out what flag will stop this incessant creation of these containers.

Comment: Did you find the ``--restart='Never'`` option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it does this is because `kubectl run` implicitly creates a deployment for the pod. Deployments are tasked with ensuring a certain number of pods are always running, so when Kubernetes detects a misalignment in the number of pods the deployment *should* be running vs the number that are actually running, it'll spin up a new one. You can remedy this by deleting the deployment: `kubectl delete deployment busybox`

Alternatively, you can temporarily kill the pods (but keep the deployment) by scaling down the deployment to run 0 pods: `kubectl scale deployment busybox --replicas=0`.

Documentation: 
https://kubernetes-v1-4.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_run/

> Create and run a particular image, possibly replicated. Creates a deployment or job to manage the created container(s).